# Create a dropdown tree with search in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I would like to create a dropdown tree with search in angularjs 1.x. I found (angularjs-dropdown-tree) https://pkempenaers.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-tree/index.html but I don't see a working example. Could someone please point me to a working example?

Comment: There's a working example of a dropdown with a search field in the link you provided. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I found http://plnkr.co/edit/wOo98cSXa12rRLZO85lr?p=preview online byt ading it to a ui.grid is not working. Does anyone have an example for it? The drop down in the grid is always empty. It works fine outside the grid